# How to define function with record argument in erlang

Tags: module, erlang, record

I want to define the structure of my function input.

This module defines my function (part of it is pseudo code):

```
-module(my_service).
-export([my_function/2]).
-type my_enum() :: 1 | 2 | 5.
-record(my_record, {id = null :: string(), name = null :: string(), myType = null :: my_enum()}).
-spec my_function(MyValue#my_record) -> Result#my_record.
my_function(ClientRequest, MyValue) when is_record(Entry, my_record) ->
    Response = client:request(get, "http://www.example.com/api?value=" + MyValue#my_record.name),
    case Response of
        {ok, Status, Head, Body} ->
            Result = parse_response(Body, my_record);
        Error ->
            Error
    end.
```

This is how I want to call it:

```
-module(test1).
-import(io, [format/2]).
main(_) ->
    application:start(inets),
    MyTestValue = #my_record{name => "test value", myType => 2},
    X = my_service:my_function(MyTestValue),
    io:format("Response: ~p", [X]).
```

So, any idea how I can force the type of the function input to be of type my_record?

Comment: The `is_record` guard in your code is one way to do it. Do you have any particular reason to use anything else?

Comment: How do you mean "force"? All the suggestions here, including your own, show ways of testing in the function that the argument it is called with is a ``#my_record`` record, and generating an error if it isn't. There is no way to get the compiler to check that the caller is calling it with the right type as Erlang is dynamically typed. There is a tool called the 'dialyzer' which can help you do that type of checking.

Answer (score 6):

It's often handy to destructure a record directly in the function argument list, which also forces that argument to have the desired record type. For example, we can slightly modify your `my_function/2` like this:

```
my_function(ClientRequest, #my_record{name=Name}=MyValue) ->
    Response = client:request(get, "http://www.example.com/api?value=" ++ Name),
    case Response of
        {ok, Status, Head, Body} ->
            Result = parse_response(Body, MyValue);
        Error ->
            Error
    end.
```

Note how we're pattern-matching the second parameter `MyValue`: we're not only asserting that it's a `#my_record{}` instance, but we're also extracting its `name` field into the `Name` variable at the same time. This is handy because we use `Name` on the first line of the function body. Note that we also keep the parameter name `MyValue` because we pass it to `parse_response/2` within the function body. If we didn't need it, we could instead write the function head like this:

```
my_function(ClientRequest, #my_record{name=Name}) ->
```

This would still have the desired effect of forcing the second argument to be of type `#my_record{}`, and would also still extract `Name`. If desired, you could extract other fields in a similar manner:

```
my_function(ClientRequest, #my_record{name=Name, id=Id}) ->
```

Both `Name` and `Id` are then available for use within the function body.

One other thing: don't use the atom `null` as a default for your record fields. The default for Erlang record fields is the atom `undefined`, so you should just use that. This is preferable to defining your own concept of `null` in the language.